# Avoiding code duplication for a function shared between two glsl shaders

Tags: webgl, shader, code-duplication

My HTML page (pipad.org/tmp/fourier02.html) contains two shaders:

```
<script type="application/glsl" id="shaderA">
    uniform vec4 a;
    vec4 f(vec4 x, vec4 y){ ... } // DUP
    vec4 main(vec4 u, vec4 v) { return f(a,u); }
</script>

<script type="application/glsl" id="shaderB">
    uniform vec4 a;
    vec4 f(vec4 x, vec4 y){ ... } // DUP
    vec4 main(vec4 u) { return f(a,u); } // notice main's sig is different
</script>
```

I hope I'm not oversimplifying, I may have to revise if I am. These shaders are used in different ways (shaderB is RTT).

As can be seen, `f` is identical in both cases.

Is there any way to avoid writing it twice?

The only way I can see is keeping the shaders as strings, which is messy because syntax highlighting no longer works and you have to do:

```
:
var
f = 
    "vec4 f(vec4 x, vec4 y){\n" +
    "...\n" +
    "}\n",

shaderA = f + 
    "uniform vec4 a;\n" +
    "vec4 main(vec4 u, vec4 v) { return f(a,u); }\n",

shaderB = f + 
    "uniform vec4 a;\n" +
    "vec4 main(vec4 u) { return f(a,u); }\n"
;
```

etc.

which is ... meh.  No clear advantage over the original. We've just exchanged duplication for ickyness.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already found, string manipulation is a common way to make shaders. Pretty much all large engines use lots of string substitution to build shaders at runtime. WaclawJasper pointed out template strings. They are a new feature of JavaScript but since pretty much all browsers that support WebGL get regular updates you can probably use then pretty safely, or you can use a polyfill.

Example

```js
var t = {
  PI: '3.14159',
  plusToPlusMinus: `
    float plusToPlusMinus(float v) {
       return v * 2.0 - 1.0;
    }
  `,
};

var shader = `
  ${t.plusToPlusMinus}
  ...
  void main() {
   a = b * ${t.PI};
  }
`;

console.log(shader);
```

outputs:

```
  float plusToPlusMinus(float v) {
     return v * 2.0 - 1.0;
  }

...
void main() {
 a = b * 3.14159;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you are looking for is [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It supports multi line strings by default.

If compatibility is an issue, `shader = ["blah", "blah"].join('\n');` is IMO cleaner than string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I moved out my common function to a separate `<script type="application/glsl" id="common">` tag and did:

```
<script> 
    :
    function joinElements(A,B) {
        return document.getElementById(A).innerHTML 
             + document.getElementById(B).innerHTML;
    }
    :
```

... and then replaced `"#shaderA"` with `joinElements("#common", "shaderA");`